# Vertical line drawn doesn't appear

Tags: itext

I'm using the following code to draw a vertical line in my PDF.

```
    logger.info("x1, y1: " + x + ", " + y1);
    logger.info("x2, y2: " + x + ", " + y2);

    dcUnder.saveState();
    dcUnder.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
    dcUnder.setLineWidth(2f);
    dcUnder.moveText(x, y1);
    dcUnder.lineTo(x, y2);
    dcUnder.closePath();
    dcUnder.stroke();
    dcUnder.restoreState();

    logger.info("Line Drawn");
```

The loggers above and below the code are printing, so I know the code is executing. But there is no line on the page. I'm trying to copy the examples in the iText in Action book, and I don't see any material differences.

I'm using a LineSeparator earlier in the code with the same dcUnder PdfContentByte, and it works fine. I don't understand why this code fails when I draw it manually. There are no errors or exceptions, just no line on the page. I assume I'm missing something simple, but I need help finding it.

Thanks!!

NOTE: Setting the line width to 2 and the color to red are just debugging settings I'm using to make the line obvious until I figure out why it doesn't appear.

Comment: Try using moveTo instead of moveText.

Comment: @mkl It appears I needed a fresh set of eyes. I'm surprised I missed that. I just got into work and was able to try it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the `moveText` by `moveTo`, you'll see your line (given sensible coordinates...), e.g.

```
    float x = 100;
    float y1 = 50;
    float y2 = 550;

    PdfContentByte dcUnder = writer.getDirectContentUnder();

    dcUnder.saveState();
    dcUnder.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
    dcUnder.setLineWidth(2f);
    dcUnder.moveTo(x, y1);
    dcUnder.lineTo(x, y2);
    dcUnder.closePath();
    dcUnder.stroke();
    dcUnder.restoreState();
```

creates

[image]

This corresponds to the samples in iText in Action, 2nd edition.